# Best technique to create fluid fullscreen layout with HTML & CSS & JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

What would be the best way to create fluid layout, which would **fill the screen** in both, **horizontally and vertically**? (The layout should be 100% height of the window, so no scrollbars should be visible nor no scrolling required)

I'm thinking purely as techniques go, since the elements of the layout will be changing.

Example could be something like this:

```
---------------------------------------
| HEADER  100% x 100px                |
---------------------------------------
|         |                 |         |
| SIDEBAR |      FILL       | SIDEBAR |
| 200px   |                 | 30%     |
| x 100%  |                 | x 100%  |
|         |                 |         |
|         |                 |         |
---------------------------------------
```

1. Header, that spans the whole screen,
2. Sidebars, that are floated to the edges, and which span the rest of the available height
3. And fill element, that fills the rest in horizontally and vertically

Currently it looks like this can only be achieved with JavaScript manipulation on window resize (as far as the height and fill goes).

But what if we **add/remove elements**, like add bar on top of the header, or take another sidebar away? The whole **layout should still be filling the screen** without any code or style changes. I'm somewhat stumped on how to approach this whole thing.

Penny for your thoughts Internet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are not targeting Internet Explorer, you can `position:absolute`, `box-sizing:border-box`, and a lot of `top`, `right`, `bottom`, `left`, `width`, and `height` to create nice full screen layouts, and you have a lot of control over where elements are placed related to its container.

With `border-box` sizing, you don't have to worry that `border` and `padding` will expand the box.

See this for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/thai/jtYDP/2/

It works in Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Heyyy! That does exactly what I was looking for! :) I do have to worry about IE but maybe that can be dealt with polyfill! Thanks!

Comment: @@thai/@@crappish -- +1. Any workarounds to get this to work in IE?

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to have JavaScript - you can do it using HTML + CSS...

There are lots of three-column solutions here:

http://css-discuss.incutio.com/wiki/Three_Column_Layouts

Edit: Height Issue

If you just want fluid with entire height, here is a solution I've mocked up on JSFiddle...

http://jsfiddle.net/Sohnee/qJjyc/

**Update:**

Here is an example with a header, to demonstrate how you take it into account...

http://jsfiddle.net/qJjyc/1/

Comment: Agreed. Everyone has their own preferences, so it's best to find what works for you.

Comment: Erm. Thee column doesn't have anything to do with this. That's the problem. Like I said, the whole thing should still fill the screen even if I remove one column. Plus, unfortunately that still doesn't have aything to do with the page/element height.

Comment: That height solution doesn't take into account that there might be elements on top of the columns, which is when things break.

Comment: The problem with that header is that it's 10%, whereas it should be 100px, and there lies the problem. :/

Answer (score 1):

My favorite way to do it is [this one](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/ultimate-multi-column-liquid-layouts-em-and-pixel-widths). No JavaScript needed.

Comment: Erm. Unfortunately that does not do anything with the page height.

Comment: @crappish: the page height issue is an entirely different beast. When content is too wide, it gets wrapped so that it takes up more vertical space. What do you do with content that's too wide _and_ too tall to fit in the viewport? Change the font size? [Fluid images](http://unstoppablerobotninja.com/entry/fluid-images/)?

Comment: That is no problem. The fill element is specified so that it will always have solution for that (fluid stuff, drag-scroll, whatnot.).

Answer (score 1):

I just kind of [rolled my own](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/LSB6Q/1/), not exactly there but I'd use it :D

Only thing is making the columns 100% high...

Comment: And that is just the reason I made this question. :)

Comment: Yeah, it's a tricky one. I will keep working on it and let you know :)

Answer (score 1):

I've modified Thai's jsfiddle to include a footer and I removed the right sidebar, I've set a min height and a min width to the main container and used more div to be able to manipulate paddings without breaking the page. I also added some jQuery to hide and show the sidebar. It works pretty well.

I had to make a web app so I used that layout.

http://jsfiddle.net/gableroux/jtYDP/35/

Hiding and showing sidebar change the size of content dynamically (using margins) so it may help some of you :). Now my app feels really good.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Gable, I was playing with this one. I try to change the `#footer-container {  height:300px; }` make it bigger so I can put a grid there, but then the left side panel doesnt show the scroll properly when resize the windows and the text is hide. How should I change it?

Comment: hmm, not using this layout anymore as it's too much dependant on javascript. Wrote this a few years ago :P. I'd probably use flexbox now if internet explorer is not a target. Check [Can I use flexbox](http://caniuse.com/flexbox/embed/) and [A Complete Guide to Flexbox on css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). If you still want this solution, I've updated the example, you had to update #main bottom value: http://jsfiddle.net/jtYDP/397/

Comment: Thanks, this will do for now. My weakness is the CSS, but at least Im not using Tables :P. I will take a look  to flexbox.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [YAML](http://www.yaml.de/en/home.html) can be of help for you.

Comment: Wow, that's not the best name choice. At first I though you were suggesting [YAML](http://www.yaml.org/), which just didn't make any sense.